SwiftUI Resolving BookmarkData does not compile
I let the user choose a music file which should then be played many times after, the app closing in between. So I need securityScope Access and so I saved the fileImport in a bookmarkData. Now I am trying to unpack this bookmark, but it doesn't work and I get an error.
Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: literals are not mutable

This is where I am trying to unpack the Bookmark.
do {
    /// Unpacking the Bookmark into our URL
    musicUrl = try URL(resolvingBookmarkData: asana.musicBookmark, options: .withSecurityScope, relativeTo: nil, bookmarkDataIsStale: false)

    musicSound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: musicUrl)
    musicSound?.play()
    musicSound?.numberOfLoops = 10000
} catch {
    print("Failed to play Music: \(error.localizedDescription).")
}

This is how I am setting the Bookmark.
/// We let the User choose a file, which is then returned as result
.fileImporter(isPresented: $chooseMusic, allowedContentTypes: [.item]) {result in
    switch result {
        case .success(let Fileurl):
            let gotAccess = Fileurl.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
            do {
                asana.musicBookmark = try Fileurl.bookmarkData()
            } catch {
                print("JSONSerialization error:", error)
            }
            Fileurl.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
    }
}

Also in all examples I read on this they used .withSecurityScope when setting the bookmark, but when I try to implement these, I get an error saying this option is not usable in iOS.
And if somebody knows of their head, is there a way to set the loop of the Audio File to infinite? It should only stop once the user leaves that view or presses stop.

I found the solution, the problem was in bookmarkDataIsStale. It has to be a boolean var to work.
var musicbool = true

musicUrl = try URL(resolvingBookmarkData: asana.musicBookmark, options: .withSecurityScope, relativeTo: nil, bookmarkDataIsStale: &musicbool)

With these changes it compiles and even can play the song after quitting the app. It works as intended!
